# How to add/remove eventSources dynamically

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Unfortunately the documentation for this on the FullCalendar site is a bit sparse.

I have 3 eventSources and I want to use a series of 3 checkboxes that when checked will display that eventSource and when unchecked will hide it.

The method for addEventSource is `.fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', source )`
The method for removeEventSource is `.fullCalendar( 'removeEventSource', source )`

I'm using FullCalendar 1.5.3 which according to the documentation

> Since version 1.5, the source parameter has become rather relaxed. You can provide an event source's Array/URL/Function or you can specify the full Event Source Object.

Do I still specify my EventSources within the main fullCalendar set-up and then use the above methods and if that is the case what is `source` in my case?

Below are my eventSources:

```
 eventSources: [               //sets up where we will get the data for claims (fullCalendar refers to them as events)
                {
                url: '../Users/json-events.aspx',   //file which generates a json feed
                type: 'GET',
                allDay: false,
                editable: false,
                data: {                 //extra params that will signify which sql script to use
                    e: 'tsb',           //gets tsb claims     
                    c: ccview,          //for this cost centre
                    t: tview,           //for this team
                    p: pid              //for this pid
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('There was an error while fetching TSB claims');
                },
                color: '#a6b28c',       //background color of block
                textColor: 'black'      //text colour of block
            },
                {
                    url: '../Users/json-events.aspx',
                    type: 'GET',
                    allDay: false,
                    editable: false,
                    data: {
                        e: 'co',            //get call out claims
                        c: ccview,          //for this cost centre
                        t: tview,           //for this team
                        p: pid              //for this pid
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('There was an error while fetching Call-Out claims');
                    },
                    color: '#ea9473',
                    textColor: 'black'
                },
                {
                    url: '../Users/json-events.aspx',
                    type: 'GET',
                    allDay: false,
                    editable: false,
                    data: {
                        e: 'ot',            //get overtime claims
                        c: ccview,          //for this cost centre
                        t: tview,           //for this team
                        p: pid              //for this pid
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('There was an error while fetching Overtime claims');
                    },
                    color: '#a8bac8',
                    textColor: 'black'
                }
            ],
```

As you can see I'm using the same URL (the difference would be the 'e' parameter)

Comment: After a lot of playing around I first got the system to remove events. The problem was bringing them back in. I've finally got them to come back in but they return back in the standard blue colour and not the colour assigned. Has anyone any ideas?

Comment: OK lets try and skin a cat another way... Could I load all events and then depending on the value of the checkboxes hide or show the div for those particular events? What div would I look for? I assume they would have the same div but with different style attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not the perfect solution, I have managed to implement this using hide/show of divs.

```
function TSBToggle() {         
        if ($("#chb_TSB").is(':checked')) {
            $('div').filter(function () {
                var match = '#a6b28c'; //match background colour for TSB
                /* true will keep this div in our wrapped set
                false will exclude div from wrapped set */
                return ($(this).css('background-color') == match);
            }).show(); // shows all div that were matched
        } else {
            $('div').filter(function () {
                var match = '#a6b28c'; //match background colour for TSB
                /* true will keep this div in our wrapped set
                false will exclude div from wrapped set */
                return ($(this).css('background-color') == match);
            }).hide(); // hides all div that were matched
        }
    }

    function COToggle() {           
        if ($("#chb_CO").is(':checked')) {
            $('div').filter(function () {
                var match = '#ea9473'; 
                return ($(this).css('background-color') == match);
            }).show(); 
        } else {
            $('div').filter(function () {
                var match = '#ea9473'; 
                return ($(this).css('background-color') == match);
            }).hide(); 
        }
    }

    function OTToggle() {
        if ($("#chb_OT").is(':checked')) {
            $('div').filter(function () {
                var match = '#a8bac8'; 
            }).show();
        } else {
            $('div').filter(function () {
                var match = '#a8bac8'; 
                return ($(this).css('background-color') == match);
            }).hide(); 
        }
    }
```

This will hide/show each of the 3 types of events I have. Unfortunately because the divs use absolute positioning they leave a gap so the solution is not perfect. Still looking for the ideal - remove all events belonging to a source (can do) - bring back events (also can do but they return in the standard blue and not coloured as required.